# would sharing a global resolved promise between many promise chains create a memory leak or have performance downsides?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, bluebird, es6-promise

I often fall on a pattern of this kind:

```
function makeSureDataWasFetched () {
  if (dataAlreadyFetched) {
    // Creating a new empty resolved promise object and returning it
    // to keep the function interface consistent
    return Promise.resolve()
  } else {
    return fetchData()
  }
}
```

So to avoid re-creating a new empty resolved promise object every time, I have been playing with the idea of sharing a unique, global resolved promise

```
const resolved = Promise.resolve()

// then, re-use this resolved promise object all over the place
function makeSureDataWasFetched () {
  if (dataAlreadyFetched) {
    // Return the shared resolved promise object,
    // sparing the creation of a new resolved promise object
    return resolved
  } else {
    return fetchData()
  }
}

function makeSureSomethingElseWasFetched () {
  if (thatSomethingElseWasAlreadyFetched) {
    return resolved
  } else {
    return fetchSomethingElse()
  }
}

// etc
```

Being referenced all over the application, this resolved promise will never be garbage collected.
Thus, if it keeps some reference to promise chains using it, those wouldn't be garbage collected either and that would create a memory leak, right?

So my question: would this kind of global resolved promise keep a reference to all those depending promise chains in Bluebird implementation? In vanilla ES6 Promises?
If not, would that have any performance downside counter-balancing the spared cost of creating new resolved promises every time?

Comment: A promise only keeps references to the promise chains until it is settled, i.e. the callbacks are called. They'll be released afterwards. Since your promise is already fulfilled, keeping the promise around does not create a leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would sharing a global resolved promise between many promise chains
>   create a memory leak or have performance downsides?

No.

Reusing and sharing the globally resolved promise just keeps that single globally resolved promise from ever being garbage collected.  It does not affect the garbage collection of other promises that may be chained to it.  They will be garbage collected when they are no longer reachable just as normally happens.

Now, it is unclear what advantage there is to sharing a globally resolved promise at all.  It should not be needed.  Anytime you want an already resolved promise, you can just create one with `Promise.resolve()` and then your code does not rely on a shared global and can be more modular.

> So my question: would this kind of global resolved promise keep a
>   reference to all those depending promise chains in Bluebird
>   implementation?

No.

> In vanilla ES6 Promises?

No.

> If not, would that have any performance downside counter-balancing the
>   spared cost of creating new resolved promises every time?

You are asking about a premature micro-optimization which is pretty much never a good idea.  If at some point in the future, you wanted to totally optimize the performance of your code, then you would profile and measure and I can promise you that you'd find 100 things you could work on that would impact your code far more than trying to share a global for a resolved promise.

---

To help you understand who has a reference to what in promise chaining and when things can be garbage collected, let me describe how chaining works.  Let's say you have the following code:

```
f1().then(f2).then(f3)
```

`f1` and `f2` both return promises which we will call `P1` and `P2`.

So, here's the progression:

1. Call `f1()` and it returns a promise `P1`.
2. Call `P1.then(f2)` which returns a new promise we will call `P3`.
3. Call `P3.then(f3)` which returns a new promise we will call 'P4'.
4. Then, at some point in the future, P1 is resolved and triggers it to call its `.then()` handlers.
5. `f2` gets called and it returns promise `P2`.
6. When the internals of the promise `.then()` code gets a return value from the `f2` `.then()` handler as a return value, it detects that this return value is a promise and it then chains that new promise `P2` to `P3`.  It does that by adding it's own `.then()` handler to `P2` so it can track its state.  Internal to `P3`, it adds this new `.then()` handler to a list of things that have to happen before `P3` can be resolved.  Note that there's no direct reference between `P2` and `P3`.  They don't even have direct references to each other.  Instead, `P3` is waiting for a specific `.then()` handler (that happens to be attached to `P2`) to be called.
7. Then, at some future time `P2` resolves.
8. This calls the internal `.then()` handler that was established in step 6 and any reference to that `.then()` handler is cleared.  This tells `P3` that it can now resolve itself and this unlinks its indirect reference to `P2`.  At this point nothing in this promise chain has any reference to `P2` any more so if there are no other references to it elsewhere in your code, it can be GCed.
9. When `P3` resolves, it calls its `.then()` handlers which will execute `f3` telling your code that the promise chain is now done.

So, from this I'm hoping you can see that chained promises don't actually store references to each other.  The parent promise ends up with a `.then()` handler on the child promise which keeps the child promise from getting GCed until the `.then()` handler is called and once that `.then()` handler is called, even the indirect connection between the two promises is severed and each is independently available for GC (as long as there are no other references to them in other code).

Per your question, if `P2` happens to be your shared, global promise that is already resolved, then step 6 would just add a `.then()` handler to it which would be called on the next tick (since the underlying promise is already resolved) and once the `.then()` handler is called, there would be no connection at all to `P2` any more, thus it doesn't matter that it's a persistent global or not.

Comment: I am aware that this register as premature micro-optimization but I found the question interesting as it underlines how I'm still not getting exactly how promises work: is there a piece of documentation or code you would recommend to better understand how those promises are linking to one another?

Comment: @maxlath - I added a bunch of info to my answer about how promise chaining works that will hopefully help you understand how garbage collection is connected to promise chaining.

Comment: "*it is unclear what advantage there is to sharing a globally resolved promise at all*" - memoisation is a very common technique that is also used with promise-returning functions. It's much easier than re-creating the result every time.

Comment: @Bergi - Are you saying that it's a desirable thing to create a node.js global and assign it `Promise.resolve()` rather than using `Promise.resolve()` whenever you need an already resolved promise?  Note, there is no **value** here that needs to be recreated.  This is just an attempt to avoid calling `Promise.resolve()`.  Yes, memoisation is useful when you have a non-trivial value you want repeated access to.  The OP's case is not that so I don't see why you'd want to complicate modularization and create a dependency on a global when it doesn't buy you anything.

Comment: It doesn't need to be in global scope, it just needs to be a static variable. To me, the OPs use case looks exactly like he's memoising `makeSureDataWasFetched`, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Bergi - It looks to me like this is the memoisation: `const resolved = Promise.resolve()` and then the variable `resolved` is used multiple places instead of calling `Promise.resolve()`.  I'm not seeing how that makes better code and it seems like micro-optimization.  And, the OP asks about making it a global and extending that use wider.  And, they ask about the GC effects of doing this.